# Regex not returning expected output in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

The list is `a = ['Aeroplane','Ramanujan','World-king','Pizza/Burger']`
I am trying to replace the items(with `-`, `/`) in the list with `Pizza_Burger` and `World_king` . Whatever the symbol is should be replaced by and underscore.

Here is my code:

```
import re
def replaceStrings(arg):
    txt =arg
    res = re.search(r'(?i)\b([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)([/-]+)([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)\b', txt)
    if res:
        pp = reg.sub(r'\1_\2',txt)
        print(pp)
        return pp



for i in a:
    replaceStrings(i)
```

But I am not getting the desired output. What is wrong in my regex.
I am a beginner in regex. Thank you

Comment: you dont need to search, do the sub directly

Comment: @Nullman I understand. But I have a list of 10,000 items. They contains strings like this.So asking. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check my regex? I think I did a slight mistake somewhere.

Comment: you arent using reg.sub correctly, it takes 3 parameters, you are giving it two.

Comment: @Nullman My goodness! Yup you are correct. I missed. Thank you. I also got a answer below. I think I am good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to clean terms is to loop over the terms and clean each term separately. You can just go for something as simple as `'World-king'.replace('/','_').replace('-','_')`

Or you can use regex for cleaning like this:

```
import re
def replaceStrings(arg):
    # each individual special character you want to clean can be put in the brackets `[]`
    pp = re.sub(r'[-/]', '_', arg)
    print(pp)
    return pp


a = ['Aeroplane','Ramanujan','World-king','Pizza/Burger']
for i in a:
    replaceStrings(i)
```

output:

```
Aeroplane
Ramanujan
World_king
Pizza_Burger
```

update: [comment added by OP]

> I took a precautionary measure making sure I have the string of the required pattern. My question is, Is it a good practice The way I
>   wrote an extra step instead of directly doing re.sub?

if you want to make sure a pattern is matched before cleaning it, that can also be done:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)\b([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)([/-]+)([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)\b')

def replaceStrings(arg):
    if pattern.match(arg):
        pp = re.sub(r'[-/]','_', arg)
        print(pp)
        return pp

a = ['Aeroplane','Ramanujan','World-king','Pizza/Burger']
for i in a:
    replaceStrings(i)
```

output:

```
World_king
Pizza_Burger
```

Comment: I took a precautionary measure making sure I have the string of the required pattern. My question is, Is it a good practice The way I wrote an extra step instead of directly doing re.sub?  Thank you

Comment: Great! Thank you. It is clear and concise now. I got the difference.

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra the pattern you are looking for seems quite complicated. If you can tell me what exactly you are looking for maybe we can simplify that.

Comment: How to parse the string like this     'Hashimoto's_thyroiditis'   Notice <<'s>> this in the string. How to remove <<'>> it and give the output as 
Hashimotos_thyroiditis

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra What you are asking for is a very custom use case. As your corpus is really large you will run into more such cases with time. Until and unless you have very clear cut `pattern` for cleaning text and removing special characters you will end up writing a lot of if conditions.

Comment: Yes. It is indeed a custom use case. I am trying to write a clear pattern. I am halfway through.

Comment: This is the code that I use for general text cleaning. You can use this for overall cleaning of text. https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/52b4ed862deaed9005bf89b7b00f4c74

But it won't solve your specific use case :/

Comment: I needed to change the while loop values. It is done. Using this function on my list is doing good. Thank you.